# Virtual template function with templated return value workaround

Tags: c++, templates, visitor-pattern

Questions about workarounds for templated functions that must be virtual are quite common here, though I couldn't find anything that helps with my problem, which is a simple variation of this question: [need a virtual template member workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939860/need-a-virtual-template-member-workaround)

The proposed approach is using type erasure leading to a very clean and simple solution. However, what if I need to return a value from the `visit()` method? The OP already had this aspect in his question, but since he never used the result it was ignored in the solution.

Now imagine this code instead:

```
template <typename T>
class BaseVisitor {
  public:
    BaseVisitor();
    T visit(BaseVisited *visited);
    virtual ~BaseVisitor();
}


class BaseVisited {
  BaseVisited();
  template <typename T>
    virtual T accept(BaseVisitor<T> *visitor) { return visitor->visit(this); };
  virtual ~BaseVisited();
}
```

We still need `accept()` to be templated, even after applying the type erasure trick. Any further ideas?

Note: I cannot use a base class for the return value, as has been suggested in some of the answers on SO, because T can stand for any base type as well (int, string etc.).

Comment: If you're not okay with closed typesystem (e.g. `std::variant<>`) and type erasure (e.g., `boost::any`, `void*`), probably your only choice is to `throw T(...);` instead of `return T;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two choices:

1. Provide a common return type for `accept()`, like [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any) or its predecessor [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any.html). Or, if you have some small finite number of possible return types, `std::variant`/`boost::variant`. This way, the member function doesn't need to be a template - but the caller has to know what to do with it.
2. Store the result, typed, in the `Visitor` object. You have to store it instead of returning it, but at least you can keep the type. You can handle this using the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). We can have different visitors that have different result types; they just store them internally:

   ```
   // a void visitor
   struct ShapePrinter : IShapeVisitor
   {
       void visit(const Square&) override { std::cout << "Square"; }
       void visit(const Circle&) override { std::cout << "Circle"; }
   };

   // a double visitor
   struct ShapePerimeterComputer : IShapeVisitor
   {
       void visit(const Square& square) override { perimeter = 4. * square.sideLength; }
       void visit(const Circle& circle) override { perimeter = 2. * M_PI * circle.radius; }

       double perimeter = 0.;
   };
   ```

Comment: No. 2. comes with wonderful side effects in multi-threaded environment unless you're locking till read.

Comment: I cannot use C++17 nor Boost, but in fact I have an own Any class that should help here. I'll try that and see if that works out nicely.