# Templated virtual member functions

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Template member function virtual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/template-member-function-virtual)

Why are templated virtual member functions not allowed?
I was just playing around a bit with some sample code and the following code snippet gives me the error

```
"member function templates cannot be virtual"

#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
class Base
{
    public: 
    template <class T> virtual void doSomething(T genVar,int val){}

};

class derivedCl:public Base
{
    public:
    template <class T> virtual void doSomething(T genVar, char ch){}
};
```

Is this a rule which the standard dictates and if so why?

Edit: I did a search before asking the Q but the dup never showed up. Now that Sbi pointed it out, I would vote for closing this one. Thanks!