# Template method over non-template method in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, class, derived

```
class A {
public:
    template<typename T> void func(size_t n, T values[]) { ... }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void func(size_t n, uint32_t values[]) { ... }
};
```

Why does function `B::func()` **not** take precedence over the function template `A::func()` when calling this code?

```
uint32_t values[5];
A* obj = new B();
obj->func(5, values);
```

Comment: Because overload resolution rules select most equal type match and most specific one (in this case, non-template one).

Comment: Some pointers from Herb Sutter http://gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm

Comment: Was **not** intended by the author?

Comment: @peoro: Yes, I think. I re-phrased it after I had missed out the "not" and posted a harsh comment explaining that there's a "not" missing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two reasons-

1. In C++ a member function only overrides a base class member function if the base class function is marked virtual.  Otherwise, C++ treats the two as independent functions that coincidentally have the same name.  This contrasts with Java, where functions atomatically override base class functions.
2. In C++, template member functions can't be marked virtual.  This is partly due to the implementation of virtual functions that's most commonly used - vtables - combined with the C++ template instantiations system. C++ treats all instantiations of the same template over different type arguments as separate functions, and generates these instantiations lazily.  This is a problem for the vtable implementation, since a vtable requires static, compile-time determination of the number of different virtual functions in a class, along with an ordering on them.  Since a template virtual function would mean an unknown number and ordering of virtual functions in the class, C++ disallows this.

Comment: re #2 see also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-member-function-template-be-virtual/2354671#2354671) to an FAQ entry.

Comment: So the only solution to my problem is to make non-template version of func in A (calling template function) and override it in B?

Comment: That should work.  Out of curiosity, why do you have a template member function that produces data of arbitrary types?

Comment: That's just one use case of that function.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `func` on a object/pointer/reference of type `A`, `A::func` gets called, since `func` is not virtual (and it cannot be: it's a template function).

Did you really test your code?

Answer (score 0):

`A::func()` isn't declared as `virtual`, so the compiler won't generate the virtual table and any other code required to invoke `B::func()` at runtime. It has nothing to do with templates.

Answer (score 0):

Because B::func is NOT an overload of A::func and can never be, no matter what you do.  Don't even try declaring A::func virtual because you can't.  Whatever it is you're trying to do, you can't.  Static and dynamic polymorphism just don't mix in C++.

If your pointer was to a B*, instead of an A*, you would expect it's version to be called.