# How to write virtual function in inner class of template class?

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, virtual-functions

I have an inner class, `myIterator`, of my template class `linearLinkedList<T>`, and I'd like to override inherited virtual methods from `simpleIterator<T>`, but the compiler is rejecting them as "templates may not be virtual." Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961909/templates-may-not-be-virtual), though, it seems like this should be possible, as it only depends on the class's type. For example method `foo` in my code below is legal. How can I implement the virtual functions of the inner class?

```
template <class T>
class linearLinkedList
{
public:
...
virtual void foo(T data); //OK
simpleIterator<T> * iterator();
private:
...
class myIterator : public simpleIterator<T>
{
  public:
    myIterator(node<T> ** head);
    virtual ~myIterator(); //inherited from simpleIterator; error when implemented
  private:
    node<T> ** prev;
    node<T> ** next;
    //functions inherited from simpleIterator<T>:
    virtual bool hasNext_impl(); //error when implemented
    virtual T next_impl();
    virtual void remove_impl();
};
...
template<class T>
virtual linearLinkedList<T>::myIterator::~myIterator() { ... }
->
linearLinkedList.h:213:1: error: templates may not be âvirtualâ
virtual linearLinkedList<T>::myIterator::~myIterator()
```

Comment: Don't put a `virtual` keyword in an out-of-class definition

Comment: You must not use the virtual keyword outside of the class definition.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Oh, silly me. Want to make that the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A member function that is not a function template itself can be marked as `virtual`, even if it's part of a class template, however:

§ 7.1.2 [dcl.fct.spec]/p1:

> *Function-specifiers* can be used only in function declarations.
>
> ```
> function-specifier:
>     inline
>     virtual
>     explicit
> ```
>
> The `virtual` specifier shall be **used only in the initial declaration** of a non-static class member function; see 10.3.

That is, you should remove a `virtual` keyword from the out-of-class definition:

```
template<class T>
virtual linearLinkedList<T>::myIterator::~myIterator() { ... }
~~~~~~^ to be removed
```