# Any way to have a template function in an abstract base class?

Tags: c++, virtual, abstract-class

I am trying to make a configuration manager class, that can store arbitrary objects by std::string.

My starting idea for my interface (abstract base class) was this (of course this is horribly incomplete)

```
class ConfigurationManager
{
public:
   static boost::shared_ptr<ConfigurationManager> create();

   template<typename T>
   virtual T getOption(const std::string& name) = 0;
};
```

But then my compiler pointed out that template's cannot be virtual(and then I realized that I cannot have exported templates anyways).

Internally I am going to be using boost::any's(pretty much a runtime checked void*), but I do not want to expose boost::any in my interface.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: @Oli To simulate the syntactically impossible interface that I posted in my question.

Comment: So you want to do polymorphic function templates, even though they aren't really possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a protected virtual abstract function returning `boost::any`, and a non-virtual, non-abstract, public template function to hide it from the users of your interface.

```
class ConfigurationManager {
protected:
    virtual boost::any getOptionProtected(const std::string& name) = 0;
public:
    static boost::shared_ptr<ConfigurationManager> create();
    template<typename T> T getOption(const std::string& name) {
        return boost::any_cast<T>(getOptionProtected(name));
    }
};
```

Comment: Ended up using almost exactly this.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach would be to pass the name of the derived type to `ConfigurationManager`:

```
template<typename Derived>
class ConfigurationManager
{
  public:
    static boost::shared_ptr<ConfigurationManager> create();

  template<typename T>
  T getOption(const std::string& name)
  {
    // call Derived::getOption
    return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->getOption(name);
  }
};
```

The derived type `Foo` would then be defined like this:

```
class Foo : public ConfigurationManager<Foo>
{
  template<typename T>
  T getOption(const std::string& name)
  {
    // do something Foo-specific here
  }
};
```

The end result is something similar to an abstract virtual function. This idiom is referred to as the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: I know this is old, but what's the point of the ConfigurationManager class in this usage of CRTP? We can't use that type to store Foo.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `boost::any` does for you, but aside from that your (only, I think) options are either 1) Make `ConfigurationManager` a template class, or 2) make `ConfigurationManager::getOption` *non*-virtual but use a separate non-template virtual function (called within `getOption`) that manages the functionality you want in your derived classes.  There are also variants on 2), such as including a pointer to an object which specifies the intended functionality of (non-virtual) `getOption`.  This object would be an instance of a class which is itself part of an inheritance hierarchy--the Strategy pattern basically.  Seems more complicated though.  So basically I am suggesting

```
class ConfigurationManager
{
   public:
      ...
      template<typename T>
      getOption(...);
   private:
      virtual getOptionSpecial(...) = 0; //Called within getOption
};
```

The top answer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-member-function-template-be-virtual) is (in part) why I think this is pretty much all you can do.