# template function in abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, abstract-class

I would like to extend an existing abstract base class with a function which is going to be templated and have as input argument an iterator to a template.

Lets consider the following example:

```
class base
{
 public:
 [...]

 template < int nT, typename T> 
 void do_something( A<nT, T>::iterator arg)
{
}

};
```

I have seen this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611318/any-way-to-have-a-template-function-in-an-abstract-base-class), but is not quite like.

edit:

```
class base
    {
     public:
     [...]

     template < int nT, typename T> 
     void do_something( typename A<nT, T>::iterator arg)
    {
    }

    };
```

The code compiles, but when I call the function I get the error

```
:-1: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: When I call this function as
shared_ptr<base_class> derived_object->do_somthing< 1, float >( array_iter); 
I get :

:-1: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: @AmiTavory
Thank you, I have typename, I just omitted for simplicity

Comment: Let me guess: you placed the code of `do_something` in a cpp file? It's template code - put it in the header.