# C++ polymorphism - calling subclass methods from superclass

Tags: c++, polymorphism, containers

I was trying to store some objects in a vector, subclasses from Animal. I structured it, so that i would have a super class, `Animal`, which had `Reptile` and `Mammal` as subclasses. So far, these should be abstract, as I implemented abstract methods on them.

Each one with subclasses, for example, `Crocodile` and `Lizard` as subclasses of `Reptile`, and `Dog` and `Cat` as subclasses of `Mammal`.

I was storing them in a vector, `std::vector<Animal*>` to have polymorphism, but I was having problems calling, for example, a `Mammal`-specific method, which doesn't make sense having in the `Animal` Superclass, because `Reptile` is a subclass of it.

```
std::vector<Animal*> _list_animals;
...
_list_animals[0] = new Dog();
_list_animals[0]->foo(); //foo is a virtual method from Animal, so no problems here

_list_animals[0]->bar(); //bar is a method from `Mammal` only, so it can't be called like this
```

How could I acess that method, without casting?

Comment: This is a design smell.  If you need to call subclass-specific methods, it's arguable that you shouldn't be maintaining a vector of pointers-to-superclass.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious
How so?

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth
Yeah, I understand what you're saying, but I don't know the kind of objects I had to store at compile time, thats why I was using it like this. Also, I use mostly methods from the superclass.

Comment: Redesign of your code structure so that you don't have this problem is your best choice. But if you insist on doing it this way, see this answer on StackOverflow: [Subclass Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848800/call-sub-class-method-from-base-class-specific-function)