# virtual function with varying return types

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am writing an interface class for different types of protocol messages.  I cannot re-write the base protocol code so to give each protocol a common interface I am creating a base class with a common interface with wrapper classes for each specific protocol.

So each wrapper class will have a common interface and then in my code to handle the protocol messages I can use polymorphism ie

```
message* msg = new protocol_a_msg(a_msg);
```

Then I can use functions with message* parameter to process etc, which is great.

However, eventually I need to get the underlying protocol message.  so I wanted to write a virtual function which gets the underlying message.  ie in base message class:

```
<type> get_msg() = 0;
```

But the trouble is  will vary. Does this mean I cannot have a virtual function because return type varies?

If I can't do this I would need to cast to the specific protocol wrapper type and use a specific function.  Which would work but I am wondering what is the best way.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

class message {
public:
   enum msg_type { PROTOCOLTYPE, BINARYTYPE, UNKNOWNTYPE };
   message(msg_type type = PROTOCOLTYPE) : type_(type) {}
   void set_type(msg_type type) { type_ = type; }
   msg_type get_type() const { return type_; }
   msg_type type_;
   virtual ~message() {}

// Can I make this a generic get underlying data virtual function?
 //  virtual underlying_msg get_msg() const { return <underlying_msg>; }

   //may also need a set_msg(msg) - or can initialise protocol msg in ctor
};


//this is existing protocol code which I cannot change
class protocol_a {
public:
   enum a_type { SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE };
   protocol_a(a_type a) : atype_(a) { }

   const char* get_data() { 
      static const char* const names[] = { "SMALL", "MEDIUM", "LARGE" };
      return names[atype_];
   }

protected:
   a_type atype_;
};

class protocol_a_msg : public message {
public:
   protocol_a_msg(protocol_a * a) : proto_(a) {}

   protocol_a* get_msg() const { return proto_; }

   protocol_a* proto_;
};


int main() {
    protocol_a a_msg(protocol_a::SMALL);
    protocol_a_msg* pa_msg = new protocol_a_msg(&a_msg);

    //retrieve underlying protocol_a msg
    protocol_a* a = pa_msg->get_msg();

    const char* s = a->get_data();

    std::cout << "protocol_a data=" << s << std::endl;

    delete [] pa_msg;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what templates are for.

Comment: A virtual method can't be templated

Comment: @nouney: Where did you got that from?

Comment: @kbok : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-member-function-template-be-virtual)

Comment: It doesn't need to be virtual, it needs to be a template.

Comment: From the OP question: _But the trouble is will vary. Does this mean I cannot have a virtual function because return type varies?_

Comment: @nouney: "A member function template cannot be virtual" and "A virtual member function cannot be a template" are two different things. A virtual member function can be a member function of a class template, hence "templated".

Comment: Then the method isn't templated, its class is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
class A {};
class B : A {};
class C : A {};

class IFoo
{
public:
    virtual A * func() = 0;
};

class BFoo
{
public:
    virtual B * func();
};

class CFoo
{
public:
    virtual C * func();
};
```

Comment: That is interesting but not really sure how it helps me?