# C++ Failing to override Pure Virtual Functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, overriding, pure-virtual

SortedList.h is an abstract template (pure virtual functions), LinkedSortedList.h derives SortedList.h and is a template, and LinkedSortedList.cpp is a template implementing the functions in LinkedSortedList.h.

My Error is when I'm trying to override the functions from SortedList.h in LinkedSortedList.h.

Method in SortedList.h:

```
virtual void clear() = 0;
```

Method in LinkedSortedList.h:

```
template <typename Elm> void SortedList<Elm>::clear() override;
```

error:

> error C3240: 'clear' : must be a non-overloaded abstract member function of 'SortedList'
>
> error C2838: 'clear' : illegal qualified name in member declaration

I've tried:

```
void SortedList<Elm>::clear(){}
```

But I still get the same error.  I've tried to find the solution on the web, but have failed.

Here is SortedList.h  It must not be changed:

```
#ifndef _SortedListClass_
#define _SortedListClass_

template <class Elm> class SortedList {
public:

  // -------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Pure virtual functions -- you must implement each of the following
  // functions in your implementation:
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Clear the list.  Free any dynamic storage.
  virtual void clear() = 0;          
                                 
  // Insert a value into the list.  Return true if successful, false
  // if failure.
  virtual bool insert(Elm newvalue) = 0;
            
  // Get AND DELETE the first element of the list, placing it into the
  // return variable "value".  If the list is empty, return false, otherwise
  // return true.
  virtual bool getfirst(Elm &returnvalue) = 0;

  // Print out the entire list to cout.  Print an appropriate message
  // if the list is empty.  Note:  the "const" keyword indicates that
  // this function cannot change the contents of the list.
  virtual void print() const = 0;

  // Check to see if "value" is in the list.  If it is found in the list,
  // return true, otherwise return false.  Like print(), this function is
  // declared with the "const" keyword, and so cannot change the contents
  // of the list.
  virtual bool find(Elm searchvalue) const = 0;

  // Return the number of items in the list
  virtual int size() const = 0;
};

#endif
```

Here is LinkedSortedList.h  This can be rewritten if needed:

```
#ifndef _LinkedSortedList_
#define _LinkedSortedList_

#include "SortedList.h"
#include "LinkedNode.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class Elm> class LinkedSortedList:public SortedList<Elm>
{
public:
    template <typename Elm> LinkedSortedList();
    virtual void SortedList<Elm>::clear();          
    virtual bool SortedList<Elm>::insert(Elm newvalue);
    virtual bool SortedList<Elm>::getfirst(Elm &returnvalue);
    virtual void SortedList<Elm>::print() const;
    virtual bool SortedList<Elm>::find(Elm searchvalue) const;
    virtual int SortedList<Elm>::size() const;

private:
    LinkedNode<Elm> *head;
    int num;
};

#endif
```

LinkedSortedList.cpp is the implementation for LinkedSortedList, and has these two lines at the end:

```
template class LinkedSortedList<int>;
template class LinkedSortedList<double>;
```

Comment: I'm trying to decide if this applies: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2354210/10077

Comment: My lack of experience with C++ means I'm blind to what I'm seeing on that page.  Could you condense it down for me?

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Are you trying to override `clear()` as a member of a `LinkedSortedList` class? Because you're declaring it as a member of `SortedList<Elm>`, which seems weird. I think you just want `void clear() override {}`. It would help to see more of each class declaration.

Comment: @zac: already did that in LinkedSortedList.cpp.

Comment: @FredLarson, Posted the files.  I was told in another question not to do this, so sorry for the lack of info. :P

Comment: @Delliardo I think you misunderstand what is being said in those responses.  Additionally, there is no need for your abstract base class to be a template.  It is defining an interface that has nothing to do with a type.

Comment: @ZacHowland: What about `Elm`? It's an argument to several of the virtual functions.

Comment: @FredLarson Good point ... I was skimming too fast and missed those :(

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I think the edit makes it clear it is NOT a duplicate of that question, as this question now shows the explicit instantiation recommended in answers to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding incorrectly. The overrides are members of your derived class, not the base class.

Also, there's no reason for your constructor to be a function template.

I think your class should look more like this:

```
template <class Elm> class LinkedSortedList : public SortedList<Elm>
{
public:
    LinkedSortedList();
    void clear() override;          
    bool insert(Elm newvalue) override;
    bool getfirst(Elm &returnvalue) override;
    void print() const override;
    bool find(Elm searchvalue) const override;
    int size() const override;

private:
    LinkedNode<Elm> *head;
    int num;
};
```

Comment: And that fixed it.  I swear I did that, or at least I think I tried that.  Thank you for your help, this has been quite the learning experience for me.  Now to implement the functions!