# Is this virtual member function template?

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions

Why does the following code work if `virtual` is not allowed on class template member functions?

```
template <typename T>
class Test {

public:

    virtual ~Test() {}  
    virtual void Func(const T&) {}
};
```

Comment: Why would in not be allowed? `class Foo : public Test<int> {};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code will not not compile if you use this syntax:

```
template <typename T> virtual Func(const T&){}
```

This has not a meaning as virtual function are bounded at runtime to allow dynamic polymorphism but if a function is a template one it's meant to be instantiated at compile time (static polymorphism).
In your case your function is not a template one so it can be declared virtual inside your template class.

Answer (score 4):

> ...if `virtual` is not allowed on class template member functions?

I think the issue here is terminological ambiguity:

- It is perfectly permissible to have `virtual` functions inside *class templates*. In fact, it could be a requirement that `Test<T>`'s destructor is `virtual` if you were to subclass `Test<T>` and delete instances of the subclass through pointers to `Test<T>`. See [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) for an extended discussion.
- What you can't do is make *function templates* virtual. See [Can a C++ class member function template be virtual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-member-function-template-be-virtual)

Answer (score 4):

You have some answers already that explain what's valid and what isn't, but let me try to word it differently to explain the confusion:

"class template member functions" is ambiguous. It could mean member functions of a class template, or it could mean template member functions of a class. The former can be `virtual` (as long as they themselves are not template member functions), the latter cannot.

It seems as if someone claimed `virtual` is not allowed on class template member functions, and meant template member functions of a class, but you interpreted it differently.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have templated `virtual` member functions(more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-member-function-template-be-virtual?rq=1)). What you have is a template class with a `virtual` member function which is completely fine.