# C++ Polymorphism template class : calling base class method instead of derived class

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I don't know why C++ compiler run the base class method (**sort** method of class **Sorting**) instead of derived class method (**sort** method of class **SelectionSort**).

```
template <typename T>
class Sorting {
public:
    virtual void sort(T* data, int size, Comparator<T> comparator) const {
    };
};

template <typename T>
class SelectionSort : public Sorting<T> {
public:
    void sort(T* data, int size, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        // my selection sort code
    };
};

template <typename T>
void Array<T>::sort(Sorting<T> algorithm, Comparator<T> comparator) {
    algorithm.sort(data, size, comparator); /// Problem is here !
};

int main() {
    int nums[] = { 2, 1, 3 };
    Array<int> arr(nums, 3);
    SelectionSort<int> sorting = SelectionSort<int>();
    AscendingComparator<int> comparator = AscendingComparator<int>();
    arr.sort(sorting, comparator);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a member function template be virtual?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-member-function-template-be-virtual)

Comment: For the same reason as if it weren't a template: object slicing. You want both parameters to be reference parameters.

Comment: try: `void Array<T>::sort(Sorting<T> &algorithm, Comparator<T> comparator) {`

Comment: Try taking the algorithm by reference in the array sort: Array<T>::sort(Sorting<T>& algorithm ...

Comment: @NathanOliver No, the member function isn't a template in this case.

Comment: It looks like you should make `Sorting` abstract, so that `sort` is only implemented for its subclasses. Then the compiler can catch this error, avoiding obscure runtime issues. (Either that, or remove the base class altogether, and use another template parameter to inject the algorithm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your specific problem is [Object Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). You look like you're coming from Java, where this would just work - but in C++, you lose all the important parts of the object when you copy it. What you need to do is take your interfaces by reference:

```
template <typename T>
void Array<T>::sort(Sorting<T>& algorithm, Comparator<T>& comparator) {
                              ^                         ^
    algorithm.sort(data, size, comparator);
};
```

And similarly within `Sorting::sort()` - which needs to take `Comparator` by reference. Note that had you made `Sorting` and abstract base class, that is have:

```
template <typename T>
class Sorting {
public:
    virtual void sort(T* , int , Comparator<T> ) const = 0;
    //                                                ^^^^
};
```

The compiler would have caught this error for you, as you cannot make an object of type `Sorting<T>` - which your code would require.

Note also as [Angew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497821/c-polymorphism-template-class-calling-base-class-method-instead-of-derived-c/29498016?noredirect=1#comment47154867_29498016) points out, your `SelectionSort` class does not actually override `Sorting<T>::sort` as it is missing the `const` modifier. The compiler would have pointed this error out to you as well if `sort()` had been pure virtual in the base class.

There's a few other Java things in your code:

```
SelectionSort<int> sorting = SelectionSort<int>();
AscendingComparator<int> comparator = AscendingComparator<int>();
```

should just be:

```
SelectionSort<int> sorting;
AscendingComparator<int> comparator;
```

Comment: Also note the missing `const` on the attempted overrider.

Comment: As `sort()` method is `const` (at least in base class) algorithm probably should be passed as const reference. Probably the same for comparator, but that is unclear.

Comment: @Barry : it works ! thank you very much, I understand it clearly :) P/s : I am a PHP developer.