# C++ calling the right virtual function

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions

I have a problem with the following situation:

```
 template<class T>
class A {
public: virtual int  f() { return 1; }
};

class BaseA : public A<BaseA> {};
class DerivedA : public BaseA, public A<DerivedA> {};
```

and when I do:

```
 BaseA* b1 = new DerivedA;
b1->f();
```

it calls `A<BaseA>::f()` instead of `A<DerivedA>::f()` and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Better post some real code that compiles. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: You have an inheritance diamond here. Use virtual inheritance to solve the issue.

Comment: `A<Base>` and `A<Derived>` are entirely different, unrelated types.

Comment: @utnapistim I don't see a diamond here. `A<Derived>` and `A<Base>` are different types.

Comment: @utnapistim: I question that.

Comment: Is your code compiling? This doesn't look compilable

Comment: template ... virtual?!  read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-member-function-template-be-virtual) first.

Comment: I changed the code in the post, now it compiles, Sorry.

Comment: @user1810087 This is a class template with a virtual member function, not a virtual member function template.

Comment: @user1810087 so there is no way to fix it?

Comment: You cannot override virtual functions by inheriting  from an additional base class. To override a function, you must define it in the class itself.

Comment: I think you could separate your `Base` behaviour into another class (something like `BaseBehaviour`), then have `struct Base : BaseBehaviour, A<Base>` and `struct Derived : BaseBehaviour, A<Derived>`. Hard to tell without more information though.

Comment: @KerrekSB: To be more precise, one cannot override a virtual function by inheriting from an additional base class *in the way shown here*. More generally it's possible by using dominance in a virtual inheritance hierarchy. Well except that for diagnostic free build it's then necessary to turn off a silly-warning in Visual C++. :(

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: No, I mean this quite generally. Consider `struct X { virtual void f() = 0; };`. There is no way to define a derived, concrete class that does not define `f` (possibly in some intermediate base), in particular, no amount of additional inheritance can implement `f` for you.

Comment: @KerrekSB: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b02aeae93604e5a9

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Ah, nice trick. Yes, that works. So I'll have to revise my statement to say "a non-virtually derived, concrete class". Virtual inheritance means that the virtual base class is considered only a base of the most derived class, which is what I wanted to cover by "intermediate base": Your `Derived` is concrete because it inherits from the concrete `Impl`.

Answer (score 1):

Additional info from the OP: this is a homework problem where class `A` can be freely changed, but classes `BaseA` and `DerivedA` cannot be changed.

Then the following is one solution, based on **dominance** in a virtual inheritance hierarhcy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

struct BaseA;

struct I
{
    virtual auto  f()
        -> int = 0;
};

template<class T>
class A
    : public virtual I
{
public:
    virtual auto  f()
        -> int override
    { cout << typeid( T ).name() << '\n'; return 1; }
};

template<>
class A<BaseA>: public virtual I {};

class BaseA : public A<BaseA> {};
class DerivedA : public BaseA, public A<DerivedA> {};

auto main() -> int
{
    BaseA* b1 = new DerivedA;
    b1->f();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to get myself some coffee, I'm just out of bed. Anyway the above *works*. Proving that I can solve things without understanding them. :)

Comment: I can't change class BaseA or class DerivedA(Homeworks :) ). I can add more classes,structs or add functions/specialization to A, so is there any other way to make b1 call A<Derived> instead of overriding f() ?

Comment: @Josh: OK, I got some coffee now. Class `BaseA` is entirely defined by class `A<BaseA>`, and you invoke via a pointer to `BaseA`, where the most derived class doesn't override anything. Thus if something isn't in `A<BaseA>` it doesn't influence the result. And `A<Derived>` certainly isn't there: it's an unrelated class.

Comment: @Josh: After consuming some more coffee, and posting a dominance example to KerrekSB, I realized **I was wrong again** (about impossibility). So, replaced answer wholesale.

Answer (score 0):

The Following program calls f from derivedA  (output : f in derived). Works fine.. anything wrong here ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class A
{
  public:
   virtual int f()
   {
       return 1;
   }
};

class BaseA : public A<BaseA>
{
  public:
  virtual int f()
  {
   cout << "f in base" << endl;
   return 1;
  }
};

class DerivedA :  public BaseA, public A<DerivedA>
{
   public:
   int f()
   {
       cout << "f in derived" << endl;
       return 1;
    }
};

main() {
    BaseA* b1 = new DerivedA;
    b1->f();
}
```

Comment: nothing wrong, but as I said in the comment below, I can't change BaseA or DerivedA. I need a way around this.