# C++ Virtual Template Class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function in a class which returns different type of objects ,

```
template <class T>
T Create(int i) {
  if(i==0) return new B();
  else return new A();
}
```

but this Create method must be virtual  , how can I make it? I got "template may not be virtual" error. thank you
Edit: I tried :  `template< class T >
     virtual T Create__Account(int i) = 0;`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-member-function-template-be-virtual , specifically sbi's answer.

Comment: I read it , but I could not understand how I can make a virtual function , and override it to return different type of objects in an inherited class

Comment: the example above makes no sense. can you post code that represents your real intent?