# Incorrect template function being called from within a templated class virtual function

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am trying to call a templated function from within an overridden virtual function of a class. Unfortunately, I can only seem to call the default implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <memory>

template<typename T1,
         typename T2>
class B;

template<typename T1,
         typename T2>
void bar(B<T1, T2> &b)
{
    std::cout << "T1 = " << typeid(T1).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "T2 = " << typeid(T2).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Default template" << std::endl;    
}

template<typename T2>
void bar(B<int, T2> &b)
{
    std::cout << "Specialized template" << std::endl;    
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void foobar(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
    std::cout << "Default template [foobar]" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T2>
void foobar(int t1, T2 t2)
{
    std::cout << "Specialized template [foobar]" << std::endl;
}

class A 
{
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}

    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template<typename T1,
         typename T2>
class B : public A 
{
public:
    B() {}
    ~B() {}

    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "T1 = " << typeid(T1).name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "T2 = " << typeid(T2).name() << std::endl;
        bar<T1, T2>(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto a = new B<int, char>();
    a->foo();

    bar<int, char>(*a);

    int i = 0;
    char b = 'b';
    foobar(i, b);
    foobar(b, b);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is (see: [here](http://cpp.sh/7sic6m))

```
T1 = i
T2 = c
T1 = i
T2 = c
Default template
T1 = i
T2 = c
Default template
Specialized template [foobar]
Default template [foobar]
```

Clearly the overridden foobar function works fine, however, for the `bar` function, the specialised version is never called. The outputs in the console show that the first template parameter is clearly an int and so the overridden bar function should be called.

I have a feeling this is related to the virtual function `foo` being incompatible with the class template [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-c-class-member-function-template-be-virtual)]. In principle I would like to generate different versions of the `B` class that will override the virtual `foo` function and call upon the appropriate specialisation of bar (depending on the class template parameters).

I am aware that I can just have partial specialisations of the B class however this leads to a lot of duplicate code and other complications with my design. (I am also aware that some of this can alleviated through templated inheritance).

I am mainly just curious as to why the correct version of `bar` is not called despite the template parameters clearly being correct. Rather than just a suggestion for a complete redesign, I would like to know why there is a conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `bar` are actually two separate template function overloads with first having priority. To define partial specialization for a function template you can to use a trick with proxy template class doing all the job:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> class
bar_impl
{
    public: static void
    Do(B<T1, T2> &b)
    {
        std::cout << "T1 = " << typeid(T1).name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "T2 = " << typeid(T2).name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Default template" << std::endl;    
    }
};

template<typename T2> class
bar_impl<int, T2>
{
    public: static void
    Do(B<int, T2> &b)
    {
        std::cout << "Specialized template" << std::endl;   
    }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2> void
bar(B<T1, T2> &b)
{
    return bar_impl<T1, T2>::Do(b);
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DlAQzNhOR8QpN81o)

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for. I should be able to add multiple specialised functions inside the bar_impl classes, this is great. Thanks.