# Template specialization of pure virtual function

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions

How can I specialize a templatized function which is defined as a pure function in the base class?

```
struct A {
    virtual void func(int a) = 0;
    //virtual void func(int a) {} // replace above line with this and it works
};

struct B : public A {
    template<typename T> void func(T t) {
        cout <<"hello"<<endl;
    }
};
template<> void B::func<int>(int a) { cout <<"hello 2"<<endl; }


int main() {
    B b;
    b.func(2);
}
```

Error:

> error: variable type 'B' is an abstract class
>       B b;
>         ^ note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'func' in 'B'
>       virtual void func(int a) = 0;

Comment: You can't mix template and virtual functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a class member function template be virtual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-class-member-function-template-be-virtual)

Comment: I believe this is not a duplicate, since the override is template specialized. And also note that I have issues only with pure virtual function.

Comment: @Nujufas the question is a bit different, but the answer is the same. `Member function templates cannot be declared virtual.`

Comment: @StackDanny acceptable, could you also explain why it works if the function is made 'not pure'?

Comment: @Nujufas it works because at that moment there are two different `func`'s in `B`. one from `A`: `A::func(int);` and one from `B`: `B::func(T);`. This forces `A` to provide implementation and therefore removes its status as an abstract class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `//virtual void func(int a) {}` // replace above line with this and it works

Replace the above line and the code compile, doesn't works.

Or, better, works but not as you expect.

The problem is that `virtual` functions and `template` functions doesn't mix very well.

So you can't make a template function that directly override a virtual function: if you define `func()` as a null virtual function

```
virtual void func(int a) = 0;
```

the base `A` class, and all derived classes, become not-instantiable until you don't define an effective `virtual` `func()` function.

Defining

```
virtual void func(int a) {}
```

the base `A` class, and all derivate, isn't not-instantiable anymore a you don't need anymore a redefinition of the virtual function.

But the `template` `func()` version is not related with virtual function.

When you call `b.func(2)` in `main()`, it's the `template`, not the `virtual` `func()` inherited from `A`, that is called. It's because the `template` `func()` "hide" the `func()` inherited `virtual` version.

You can "un-hide" the `virtual` `func()` version in `B` adding, in the body of `B` definition

```
using A::func;
```

This way, calling `b.func(2);` in `main()`, the `virtual` version inherited by `A` is called and the template specialization of `func()`, so the `std::cout <<"hello 2" << std::endl;` instruction, ins't executed anymore.

Now... if I understand correctly, you want a `template` `func()` function that, in case of `T == int` join the virtual specialization.

The only way I see is define the `virtual` `override` in `B`

```
void func (int a) override // override, so necessarily virtual
 { std::cout <<"hello 2" << std::endl; }
```

and call it from the `template` specialization

```
template <>
void B::func<int> (int a)
 { func(a); } // call the virtual override version
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
 { virtual void func(int a) = 0; };

struct B : public A
 {
   void func (int a) override
    { std::cout <<"hello 2" << std::endl; }

   template<typename T>
   void func (T t)
    { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; }
 };

template <>
void B::func<int> (int a)
 { func(a); }


int main ()
 {
   B{}.func(2); // call directly virtual func()
   B{}.func<int>(2); // call template func() specialization that call virtual func()
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Virtual function could be overridden by only non-template functions. In this case,

> Then this function in the class Derived is also virtual (whether or not the keyword virtual is used in its declaration) and overrides Base::vf (whether or not the word override is used in its declaration).

And note that function templates can't be [virtual functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual);

> Functions templates cannot be declared virtual.

From the standard, [[temp.mem]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.mem#4)

> A specialization of a member function template does not override a
>   virtual function from a base class. [ Example:
>
> ```
> class B {
>   virtual void f(int);
> };
>
> class D : public B {
>   template <class T> void f(T); // does not override B​::​f(int)
>   void f(int i) { f<>(i); }     // overriding function that calls the template instantiation
> };
> ```
>
> — end example ]

About your question,

> why it works if the function is made 'not pure'?

The compliation error disppears but it still doesn't work as you expected; the function template in the derived class doesn't *override* the virtual function of the base class. You can check it with [dynamic dispatch](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual):

> If a derived class is handled using pointer or reference to the base class, a call to an overridden virtual function would invoke the behavior defined in the derived class.

Note that you should use pointer or reference to make dynamic dispatch works, e.g.

```
B b;
A* pa = &b;
pa->func(2);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oLemGg1wAeXuwOH0)

You can also apply [override specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) to help you confirm *overridding*.

Comment: I'm not declaring the functions template virtual.

Comment: You can only override with a virtual functions. Overrides are implicitly virtual. Try marking your function as `override`

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot that still won't work if the function that overrides is templated.

Comment: @StackDanny Pertty sure they are saying mark it `override` so they can get a compiler error saying templates can't be used.

Comment: The quoted example from the Standard shows exactly how to make the derived class act like the template does override the virtual function, if that's what you want: define an exact override which just calls the template. In the question's example, this looks like `void func(int a) override { func<>(a); }` in the definition of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be considered besides the point but there's a very nice mnemonic that you can use when designing with templates:

Virtual functions - dynamic polymorphism (solved at runtime through vtable)

Template specialization - static polymorphism (solved at compile time through type info)

Don't try to solve one with the other.

In your case you are attempting to provide a body to a virtual method (solve a runtime polymorphism) through template specialization.