# Need to call method on member before calling base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have code similar to the following:

```
template<class BASE_TYPE = COdbcQuery>
class CRemoteQuery : public BASE_TYPE
{
    CRemoteDatabase m_Db;

public:
    CRemoteQuery()
        : BASE_TYPE(&m_Db)
    {
    }

    ~CRemoteQuery()
    {
    }
};
```

My problem is that `m_Db.Open()` must be called before passing `m_Db` to the base constructor.

If I call a method as an argument to the base constructor that calls `Open()`, it fails because `m_Db` has not yet been initialized.

I tried creating a virtual method in the base class, which would be called during initialization and this class could override, but template classes cannot override virtual methods.

Restructuring my base classes so that `m_Db` doesn't need to be opened first raises a lot of difficult issues. Is there no way to do this?

Comment: While I agree with @Sam Varshavchik, I think it highlights another issue. Given separation of responsibility, should the `CRemoteQuery` class handle the opening of the database, or should _Dependency Injection_ be used to provide you with a database that is already open? I'd opt for the latter, but you could just as easily use the comma operator like so: `BASE_TYPE((static_cast<void>(m_Db.Open()), &m_Db)) {}`

Comment: @jfh: I'm not even sure how I'd approach this using DI. This class saves a lot of typing by managing its own database for times when I just need a query. At any rate, I tried to explain in my question that I attempted your suggestion. But if fails because `m_Db` has not yet been constructed.

Comment: @Johnathan Wood well you could try explicitly constructing `m_Db` in that very same comma operator expression ala placement `new`, but that's also a big code smell as well. IMO this probably is indicative that you should refactor and introduce factories and the like, as the idea that you get a resource whose lifetime is indeterminate smells... smelly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sequence of events can be easily implemented by making a small design change:

```
class CRemoteDB {

protected:
    CRemoteDatabase m_Db;

    CRemoteDB()
    {
          m_Db.open();
    }
};

template<class BASE_TYPE = COdbcQuery>
class CRemoteQuery : private CRemoteDB, public BASE_TYPE
{

public:
    CRemoteQuery()
        : BASE_TYPE(&m_Db)
    {
    }

    ~CRemoteQuery()
    {
    }
};
```

Parent classes always get constructed in declaration order. The `CRemoteDB` parent class gets constructed first, and `CRemoteDatabase::open()` gets called in the parent class's constructor.

Then `BASE_TYPE` gets constructed, and gets a pointer to the opened `m_Db`.

`CRemoteQuery` can access `m_Db` from its parent class no differently than it would be if it was its own class member.

> but template classes cannot override virtual methods.

P.S. Whoever told you that was wrong. Template classes can certainly override virtual methods. I've got a massive hierarchy of templates here, all overriding virtual methods of their parent classes, left and right.

Comment: Another possible solution might be to create a method, that does such initialization, and use the result of it, to pass to the base class, such as: `auto& initAndReturn {m_Db.open (); return m_db;} CRemoteQuery () : BASE_TYPE (&initAndReturn ()) {}`

Comment: Thanks, although an odd fix this seems to be the best possible answer. As far as virtual methods, I tried overriding a virtual method from the base class but it never got called. And when I Googled it, I found pages like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-class-member-function-template-be-virtual).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: As described in my question, I attempted that but it failed because `m_Db` has not yet been constructed.

Comment: @JonathanWood Hmm.. I contemplated if such code was undefined behavior, or not, for the reason, that you described. But, I thought, that I remembered seeing similar code, and it _seemed_ to work fine.. Perhaps my mind is playing tricks on me, and I am misremembering things.. I, probably need to go to sleep then :/

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius depending on how you use the member it may not matter-- caching a reference to something I'll use later, for example. Initialization logic for a database, that be ugly.

Comment: The other question explains that virtual functions cannot be templates. It says absolutely nothing about a template class overriding a virtual function. These are two completely unrelated things. In fact, with modern C++, you can ***require*** that a template class, if it defines a particular function, it must override some virtual function from some inherited class, otherwise a compilation error results. This prevents the template from being instantiated with a wrong class that the template is not designed for.