# C++ Inheritance with templates undefined reference error

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I want to implement a base class with multiple children.

#### Base Class

```cpp
    template <typename T>
    class Trigger
    {
    protected:
        T threshold;
        Trigger(T a_threshold) : threshold(std::pow(10, a_threshold / 20)){};
    public:
        void setThreshold(T a_threshold)
        {
            threshold = std::pow(10, a_threshold / 20);
        }
        virtual bool operator()(const T &first, const T &second) const;
        virtual ~Trigger() = default;
    };
```

#### Derived Class

```cpp
    template <typename T>
    class ZeroCrossingRisingTrigger : public Trigger<T>
    {
    public:
        ZeroCrossingRisingTrigger(void) : Trigger<T>(0.){};

        bool operator()(const T &first, const T &second) const override
        {
            return (first <= 0) & (second > 0);
        }
    };
```

#### Usage in the main file

```cpp
#include "Trigger.hpp"
int main([[maybe_unused]] int argc, [[maybe_unused]] char const *argv[])
{
    Trigger::ZeroCrossingRisingTrigger<double> trig;
    return 0;
}
```

But on I get the following error when I try to compile it:

> (...): undefined reference to `Trigger::Trigger::operator()(double const&, double const&) const'

I don't understand why I get this error because I implemented the operator exactly as written in the error message.

Comment: it is not defined you just delared it

Comment: virtual and template don't mix very well together https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-class-member-function-template-be-virtual

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Would you recommend to implement it using CRTP?

Comment: Either provide an implementation in the base class or make it pure (`virtual bool operator()(const T &first, const T &second) const = 0;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined an implementation for `operator()` for `Trigger<T>`. An option would be to make `Trigger` an abstract base class by making the operator member function a pure virtual function:

```
virtual bool operator()(const T &first, const T &second) const = 0;
```

Alternatively, you can provide an empty implementation.

On a side-note, in the constructor of `ZeroCrossingRisingTrigger` you pass `0.0` as an argument for the base class constructor. This sort of hints there is no need for `ZeroCrossingRisingTrigger` to be templated itself, unless you want to control the type of the `0.0` literal from the outside.