# Override parameter pack declaration and expansion loci

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

I have a simple interface setter:

```
template<typename Interface>
struct FrontEnd
{
  virtual void inject(Interface*& ptr, Client* client) = 0;
}
```

I want to implement these interfaces through parameter packs like this:

```
template<typename ... Is>
struct BackEnd : public FrontEnd<Is>...
{
   void inject(Is*& ptr, Client* client) override
   {
      ptr = someStuff<Is>.get(client);
   }
};
```

However this fails with `parameter pack not expanded with '...'`. I couldn't find something similar to this in [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). I have no clue where the expansion loci should go (assuming this is even legal, which I'm leaning toward no). **Any idea how to provide overrides for every type in a parameter pack?**

Comment: FrontEnd only accepts one interface template parameter, so you can't use parameter packs in your inheritance anyway. So what are you trying to do? Mixing templates with virtual functions isn't really what I would recommend anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354210/can-a-class-member-function-template-be-virtual)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, the first ... is expanding FrontEnd<Is> so for every Is, BackEnd has a base class that it should be able to override

Comment: @PepijnKramer I'm already aware that virtual methods cannot be templated, and as a matter of fact, `inject` is not a method template

Comment: Sorry guys I missed that, and I was a bit too quick to answer.

Comment: There is an exhaustive list of allowed expansion loci, and the one you want just isn't there.

Comment: @lurscher list of allowed expansion loci: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Expansion_loci

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want something like this

```
  template<typename Is>             
  struct OneBackEnd : public FrontEnd<Is>
  {                                 
     void inject(Is*& ptr, Client* client) override { /* whatever */ }
  };                                
                                    
  template<typename ... Is>         
  struct BackEnd : public OneBackEnd<Is>...
  {                                 
      using OneBackEnd<Is>::inject...;
  };
```

Comment: Very clever. FWIW `structs` default to `public` inheritance, so it can be omitted.

Comment: clever indeed! I spent over an hour thinking how to workaround this and this didn't came up