# Dependent vs Non-dependent Name in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, lookup

I am learning templates in C++. So reading examples from different [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)(including SO). One such example whose statement i am unable to understand(or rather i think is incorrect) is given [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766399/17881448):

```
class Base {
protected:

    template <typename T1>
    void print_pi() {
        std::cout << (T1)3.141596 << std::endl;
    };

};
template <typename T2>
class Derived : public Base {
};

template <typename T3>
class DoubleDerived : public Derived<T3> {
public:
    void test() {
        print_pi<int>(); // This creates error, however changing to Base::print_pi<int>(); works.
    }
};
```

The user of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766399/17881448) says:

> In the class Derived the name print_pi is a **dependent name**.

My question is that isn't `print_pi` a non-dependent name? I mean it doesn't doesn't depends on a template parameter. For instance, `print_pi<T>` is a dependent name but in OP's code inside the derived class `DoubleDerived` the name `print_pi` is non-dependent IMO. Can someone tell me why the user says that `print_pi` is a dependent name. I mean even `print_pi<int>` is non-dependent. I was thinking of writing an answer there saying that `print_pi` is a non-dependent name and according to [Non-dependent name lookup members](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members), the problem is that  the compiler does not look in dependent base classes  when looking up nondependent names but then some people closed the question.

Am i right in saying that the currently accepted answer is incorrect in saying that `print_pi` is a dependent name?

Comment: The `print_pi` function depends on which `Derived<>` you inherit from, so it is dependent.

Comment: Remind that `Derived<T3>` might be specialized, so `DoubleDerived` might not inherit from `Base`. `print_pi<int>();` IS `Derived<T3>::print_pi<int>();` which turns to be `Base::print_pi<int>();`.

Comment: @Jarod42 So are you saying that because `print_pi<int>();` is the same as `Base::print_pi<int>();` so `print_pi` is non-dependent? Or are you saying the because `print_pi<int>();` is the same as `Derived<T3>::print_pi<int>();` so `print_pi` is dependent. Sorry if i didn't correctly interpret your last comment.

Comment: It is dependent. `DoubleDerived` doesn't know it inherits from `Base` (and with specialization, it might not inherits from `Base`). (it only inherits from `Derived<T3>`). My last sentence was to say that by "hazard", the method finally comes from non-template class, but it is irrelevant. the only **direct** base class of `DoubleDerived` is template, so access of base class member should use dependent notation (as `this->` or `Derived<T3>::` (and extra `template` because of `<int>`)).

Comment: @Jarod42 Ok so if it is dependent, then the rule *"compiler does not look in dependent base classes when looking up **nondependent** names"* does not apply to `print_pi` right? If yes, then since `print_pi` is dependent so compiler should look into the dependent base class(??) as the rule quoted above only applies to non-dependent names and it should find the inherited `print_pi`. What is happening here, can you explain as an answer if you got time. Thanks for the discussion. But comments are many times deleted on SO.

Comment: Our wording *"it is dependent"* is pedantically wrong, it should be *"it should be dependent (to compile)"* as we want `print_pi<int>()` to refer to the one from template base class `Derived<T3>`...

Answer (score 3):

> My question is that isn't `print_pi` a non-dependent name?

- As written, `print_pi<int>` is a non-dependent name, so according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Template_definition)

  > For a non-dependent name used in a template definition, unqualified name lookup takes place when the template definition is examined.

  We cannot look into base class (which is template), and no (template) function `print_pi` exist in global scope. So the compilation error.
- `Base::print_pi<int>();` is also not dependent. [qualified name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup#Class_members) takes place:

  > If the lookup of the left hand side name comes up with a class/struct or union name, the name on the right hand side of :: is looked up in the scope of that class (and so may find a declaration of a member of that class or of its base), with the following exceptions [..]

  Notice that it is not yet checked that `Base` is really a base of the class ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Pb3f4ajqq)).
  It would be done once the method would be instantiated ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xbnsoY3aj))
- `this->template print_pi<int>();`/`Derived<T3>::template print_pi<int>();` are dependent. and so, from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Template_definition)

  > For a dependent name used in a template definition, the lookup is postponed until the template arguments are known

  So `print_pi<int>()` can be found in base classes (if present [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/84bzohaW6) (else error happens [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EjTb1f1d4))).

Comment: You said in your current answer that `print_pi<int>` is non-dependent so the quoted statement from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766399/17881448) is incorrect in saying that it is dependent right? Similarly in one of your comment you also said that it is dependent.

Comment: As-is, the name is not dependent, (so would produce compile error). We want it to be a dependent-name. As (wrong) shortcut, we often said *"it is dependent"* instead of *"it should be dependent"*. It is the case in the answer too, answerer provide ways to make it dependent.